# Using jQuery to tell if file input field is empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a PHP form with a file input field, and two text input fields. What I want to do is use jQuery to check if the file input field is empty, and if it's not, then show a specific div, but the following code does not work:

```
<input type="file" name="blog-entry-image" id="blog-entry-image" />

var fileInput = $.trim($("#blog-entry-image").val());
if (fileInput.length > 0) {
        $("#new-blogentry").click(function() {
        $("#sending").show();
        return true;
    }); 
}
```

"new-blogentry" is the submit button, and "sending" is a div with an animated gif.

Comment: You should do the test INSIDE the click handler. You're testing the length when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="file" name="blog-entry-image" id="blog-entry-image" />

$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#blog-entry").click(function() {
        var fileInput = $.trim($("#blog-entry-image").val());
        if (fileInput && fileInput !== '') {      
                $("#sending").show();
                return true;    
        }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `fileInput.length > 0` to

```
fileInput != "" && fileInput.trim() != ""
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it have a length function? It's a string, it has a length.

Answer (score 0):

You have things backwards. You need to get the file input value after the user clicks.

```
$('#new-blogentry').click(function() {
    var fileInput = $.trim($("#blog-entry-image").val());
    if (fileinput.length > 0) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('#new-blogentry').val()==''))
```

is enough to check if the file input is empty

Answer (score -1):

I suggest  you to use jquery validator plugin for all frontend based validation
http://jqueryvalidation.org/